# Windows in VM viewed by a Thin Client using LTSP

Tags: server, virtualbox, windows, ltsp

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server installed with LTSP and Virtualbox. I want to do a remote desktop (if it's possible) where my client can view or access the Windows from the Virtualbox using LTSP.

My /var/lib/tftpboot/ltsp/i386/lts.conf has the following configuration

```
[DEFAULT]
SCREEN_07 = "xfreerdp"
RDP_SERVER = "192.168.2.115"
```

When I tried booting my thin client, it only shows a black screen with the arrow. xfreerdp is used here since there is an error regarding rdesktop.

If it helps, without the following configuration, Ubuntu can be accessed by the client.

Comment: Very nice idea. Does it work if you connect from fat graphical desktop session from LTSP-client to VirtualBox VRDP via Remmina or windowed `xfreerdp`?